# jQuery event won't fire on HTML form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked but all the solutions I've tried haven't worked for me. What I want it to do is trigger some jQuery code when the form element is submitted.
Here's my code.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
        alert('hi');
            var word10 = <?php echo $word10; ?>;
            var word20 = <?php echo $word20; ?>;
            var word1Txt = <?php echo $word1Txt; ?>;
            var word2Txt = <?php echo $word2Txt; ?>;

            $('div.word1').prepend("<h3 class='header'>hi" + word1Txt + "</h3>");
            $('div.word2').prepend("<h3 class='header'>hi" + word2Txt + "</h3>");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Word" name="word1" autofocus>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Second Word" name="word2" autofocus>
    <input class="btn btn-primary form-submit" type="submit" value="Compare">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form using ajax - if not the page is going to change and executing js before a page change doesn't make sense.

Comment: Other than the fact you're using `bind`, which was deprecated years ago (look at `on`), that should work (although it may not do what you expect, those changes won't last long) **if** the PHP parts have been processed by the PHP engine. If not, you should be getting a syntax error in the web console. Please show us what the browser actually receives, rather than the PHP source.

Comment: @jcuenod: Well, it can do (if you're filling in hidden fields, etc.), but yeah, the changes being made above wouldn't last long. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .on() or .submit() instead and if your vars are supposed to be strings, quote them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
        alert('hi');
            var word10 = '<?php echo $word10; ?>';
            var word20 = '<?php echo $word20; ?>';
            var word1Txt = '<?php echo $word1Txt; ?>';
            var word2Txt = '<?php echo $word2Txt; ?>';

            $('div.word1').prepend("<h3 class='header'>hi" + word1Txt + "</h3>");
            $('div.word2').prepend("<h3 class='header'>hi" + word2Txt + "</h3>");
    });
});
```